# ggplot2: how to add p_values using stat_compare_means() on facet_wrap() with scales = free

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, ggpubr

I'm trying to add p-values on multiple graphs using ggplot2, and it works well (fig.1) until I try to use scales ="free". When I add scales free, It receives a `Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in stat_compare_means(:
group1, p must resolve to integer column positions, not NULL`

My dataframe:

```
    > burst.data
      Host Clade   Phage Burst.Size
1   CC9605     A S-TIP28         20
2   CC9605     A S-TIP28         25
3   CC9605     A S-TIP28         38
4   CC9605     A S-TIP28         44
5   CC9605     A S-TIP28         56
6   CC9605     A S-TIP28         56
7   CC9605     A S-TIP28         59
8   CC9605     A S-TIP28         61
```

Code with no scales = free:

```
ggplot(burst.data, aes(Phage, Burst.Size,fill=Clade))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.75,outlier.size=5,size=1.5)+
  facet_wrap( ~ Host,nrow = 1)+
  stat_compare_means( )
```

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q8Uj.jpg)

but when I try to show only the relevant data for each plot using scales = "free"
the stat_compare_means( ) resives a warnig, and  not adding the p-values to the plots:

```
> ggplot(burst.data, aes(Phage, Burst.Size,fill=Clade))+
+   geom_boxplot()+
+   facet_wrap( ~ Host,scales = "free",nrow = 1)+
+   stat_compare_means( )
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`:
`group1`, `p` must resolve to integer column positions, not NULL 
2: Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`:
`group1`, `p` must resolve to integer column positions, not NULL 
3: Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`:
`group1`, `p` must resolve to integer column positions, not NULL
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYOQn.jpg)

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but maybe you can avoid this whole issue if this package is useful to what you are trying to achieve:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot